# Connection problem using Siddhi with NATS server

Tags: java, wso2, siddhi, nats.io

I would like to use Siddhi stream processor to read messages from a NATS server. I have installed the following software:

- NATS server v2.1.6 (on a standalone server)
- Siddhi siddhi-runner-5.1.2 (as a binary standalone on another server on the same LAN)
- Siddhi extension for NATS 2.0.10, with the following dependencies:
  protobuf-java-3.9.1.jar, java-nats-streaming-2.2.2.jar,
  jnats-2.6.5.jar (anyway I don't use streaming option)

I use the following siddhi application:

```
@App:name("TestNATS")

@source(type='nats', @map(type='text'), destination='test.message', bootstrap.servers='nats://192.168.50.173:4222')
define stream inputStream (name string, age int, country string);

@sink(type='log', prefix='LOGGER')
define stream OutputStream(name string, age int, country string);

@info(name='HelloWorldQueryNATS')
from inputStream
select name, age, country
insert into OutputStream;
```

When Siddhi starts it seems to connect with `NATS server` without problems, but after the initial handshake, Siddhi throws the following `exception`:

```
[2020-04-10 10:55:00,441]  INFO {org.wso2.msf4j.internal.websocket.WebSocketServerSC} - All required capabilities are available of WebSocket service component is available.

[2020-04-10 10:55:00,549]  INFO {org.wso2.msf4j.analytics.metrics.MetricsComponent} - Metrics Component is activated

[2020-04-10 10:55:00,552]  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.databridge.agent.internal.DataAgentDS} - Successfully deployed Agent Server

[2020-04-10 10:55:01,163]  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.analytics.idp.client.core.utils.IdPServiceUtils} - Enabling default IdPClient Local User Store as configuration is not overridden.

[2020-04-10 10:55:01,167]  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.analytics.idp.client.core.utils.IdPServiceUtils} - IdP client of type 'local' is started.

[2020-04-10 10:55:06,915] ERROR {io.siddhi.extension.io.nats.source.NATSSource} - Error while connecting to NATS server at destination: test.message

[2020-04-10 10:55:06,918] ERROR {io.siddhi.core.stream.input.source.Source} - Error on 'TestNATS'. Error while connecting to NATS server at destination: test.message Error while connecting at Source 'nats' at 'inputStream'. Will retry in '5 sec'. io.siddhi.core.exception.ConnectionUnavailableException: Error while connecting to NATS server at destination: test.message


Caused by: java.io.IOException: stan: connect request timeout
```

and restarts the connection process continuously, so in the logs of `NATS server` we can see the following messages:

```
cid:1 - Client connection created

cid:1 - <<- [CONNECT"lang":"java","version":"2.6.0","name":"1586508901596_66035_83044","protocol":1,"verbose":false,"pedantic":false,"tls_required":false,"echo":true}]

cid:1 - <<- [PING]

cid:1 - ->> [PONG]

cid:1 - <<- [SUB _STAN.acks.TSHykWgo2B6Lv2xW8b1Bfd 1]

cid:1 - <<- [SUB _INBOX.TSHykWgo2B6Lv2xW8b1BaH 2]

cid:1 - <<- [SUB _INBOX.TSHykWgo2B6Lv2xW8b1Bcx 3]

cid:1 - <<- [SUB _INBOX.4bm5CWKphBwldfvnGCxxJd.* 4]

cid:1 - <<- [PUB _STAN.discover.test-cluster _INBOX.4bm5CWKphBwldfvnGCxxJd.4bm5CWKphBwldfvnGCxxa9 88]

cid:1 - <<- MSG_PAYLOAD: ["\n\x191586508901596_66035_83044\x12\x1d_INBOX.TSHykWgo2B6Lv2xW8b1BaH\x18\x01\"\x16TSHykWgo2B6Lv2xW8b1BXb(\x050\x03"]

cid:1 - Client Ping Timer

cid:1 - ->> [PING]

cid:1 - <<- [PONG]

cid:1 - <<- [UNSUB 1]

cid:1 - <-> [DELSUB 1]

cid:1 - <<- [UNSUB 2]

cid:1 - <-> [DELSUB 2]

cid:1 - <<- [UNSUB 3]

cid:1 - <-> [DELSUB 3]

cid:1 - Client connection closed

cid:1 - <-> [DELSUB 4]

cid:2 - Client connection created
```

The `NATS server` is the same I use with a pub-sub application using `Nodejs` and it works fine. I tried also to use the last Siddhi `docker` package but the result is the same.

Where could be the mistake ?

Answer (score 0):

Using nats-streaming-server instead of nats-server, connection problem no longer occurs.
Thanks.